# Searching for simple, user friendly software for browsing photos on touch screen monitor

Tags: software, presentation

At events I take photos and display them on a multi-touch screen, for people to view and browse.  Lightroom is good but I'm looking for a simpler software which allows people to easily scroll through the thumbnails, view images individually and identify the filename (similar interactivity to how they'd be used to browsing photos on an iPhone or iPad.  Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: What platform are you working with? (PC? Tablet?, Windows 8, ???)

Comment: Unfortunately - the Windows 8 world is pretty much a mess. Developers are building apps for Touch, non-Touch, Touch enabled and mobile platforms, so there is a lot of confusion around what works with which platform. My traditional "go to" solutions do not work well with a touch screen, so I have been experimenting with alternatives. So far, I have not found a viable solution that works with the Touch interface.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the `Operating System` but if it's `Windows` you should try **`Picasa`**'s photo viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the [video embedded into this website](http://www.multitouch-software.com/) and it looks quite good, not to mention that it is free so it's worth a try?

I have never used it however, so I am not sure whether it's actually good or not. Sorry if it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Photoshop Elements to edit my images, and it does come with an organizer. However I've started using Picasa 3 from google to organize my photos. It scans entire computer or selected folders, monitors them for new images, and one click will upload to your Google+ account. That was enough for me, just an easy way to sort through and organize them and then upload them.

But then I found the "People" feature, basically, a facial detection software integrated that when you tag a face, it puts into a "people" folder, and it shows all sorts of options. Example: other people in this folder. touch the second person and it filters to show images that contain those 2 or 3 or however many faces you need.

Best part? Free!!

(And I use a touchscreen laptop)

Comment: But..... does it have a touch screen photo browser?